# symfony 2 form string missing first character

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have an app using **symfony 2.2** that has a file upload form, and another 'reportbuilder' form.

The issue I'm having is that **when any of my input field values begin with a 'c', that letter is dropped**. So if the field is submitted with a value of 'cat', the value after binding will become 'at'.

- This only appears to occur with strings that begin with 'c'
- This issue happens on any strings on any of my forms
- The issue happens during the $form->bind() method (or somewhere therein - I've verified that the post variables are correct up to that point)
- This issue occurs on my PREPROD box, but not my DEV box (environments SHOULD be the same, haven't done an extensive comparison to find a needle in a haystack ... both Redhat installs)

Based on some searching I've done, I suspect it may have something to do with character encoding (which I have attempted to compare between environments), but I'm somewhat at a loss.

I can provide some code if it helps, though since the issue is only occurring on one server and not another, I'm not sure which (if any) of the symfony code will help.

Does any of this stand out as a rookie encoding oversight or something like that?

**Edit:** *This happens with any number of leading 'c's, so 'cat' and 'ccat' and 'Ccccccat' will all be converted to 'at'*

**Edit2:** *I'm able to manually set the text field from the post variable after bind as a workaround( `$document->setName($postvars['name'])` ). It becomes more of an issue with the 'Reportbuilder' form, which has a variable number of nested forms (report has one or more tabs, tabs have one or more extra columns, etc) - so a similar workaround is clunky and not ideal*

**Edit3:** *Adding code*

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        ...
        $document = new Document();

        $form   = $this->createForm(new DocumentType($em,$user), $document);

        /// Here the name variable in the request is 'cat', as expected
        $form->bind($this->getRequest());
        /// Here the value of the 'name' parameter in the form is 'at'

        ...

    }
}
```

document.orm.yml:

```
Finance\GstBundle\Entity\Document:
    type:  entity
    manyToOne:
      report:
        targetEntity: Report
        mappedBy: report
      user:
        targetEntity: Finance\UserBundle\Entity\User
        mappedBy: user
    oneToMany:
      doctabs:
        targetEntity: Doctab
        mappedBy: document
      tabgroups:
        targetEntity: Tabgroup
        mappedBy: document
    table: document
    fields:
      id:
        type: integer
        id: true
        generator:
          strategy: AUTO
      name:
        type: string
        length: 255
        nullable: true
      path:
        type: string
        length: 255
```

... and the DocumentType definition:

```
namespace Finance\GstBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class DocumentType extends AbstractType
{
    protected $em;
    protected $user;

public function __construct($em=null,$user=null){
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->user = $user;
}

public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{



        $builder
            ->add('report','entity',array(
                'class' => 'FinanceGstBundle:Report',
                'property'=>'name',
                'empty_value' => '--Choose a Template--'
            ))
            ->add('name')
            ->add('file')
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Finance\GstBundle\Entity\Document'
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'finance_gstbundle_documenttype';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show your code? specifically _where_ you're "losing" the characters? Also, are c's within the the body of text removed as well? ie `tack -> tak `?

Comment: Maybe your form definition where you buiold the form could be helpful.

Comment: @CarrieKendall - the modification only occurs with leading characters - so tack will remain correctly as 'tack'

Comment: that would leave me to believe it isn't related to character encoding.

Comment: Edits above with code

Comment: I also tried disabling twig auto-escape to eliminate that - this one is killing me because I don't understand how the exact same code would be behaving differently :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After patching RHEL on all 3 (dev/pre/prod) boxes, the issue has resolved itself. I'm doing a post-mortem to attempt to identify the specific package that caused the bug we were experiencing.

Our versions of RHEL were in different 'states' on the different servers. PRE/PROD were signifigantly further behind in system patches than Dev.

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this issue? I've just started experiencing it on a production server also running Red Hat. It's been driving me crazy trying to work out the cause!

Comment: Sadly I didn't; It wasn't practical to spend any time identifying what had changed. If it helps, we're running RHEL 5.10 (Tikanga) - and the issue resolved by updating packages - I recall suspecting it had something to do with a specific package (maybe it was libxml2?), though I wasn't able to verify it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:** where `'cat'` becomes `'at'`?

<kbd>1</kbd> Disable javascript to make sure it doesn't update your `name` value on submit.

<kbd>2</kbd> Make sure the value submitted is 'cat'

```
$form->get('name')->getData(); //should return 'cat'
```

Note: it's mentioned you've done this in your post but we don't see the code.

<kbd>3</kbd> You might have a listener somewhere that reacts to POST_BIND:

```
$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_BIND, $yourListener);
```

<kbd>4</kbd> Maybe your using a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers), and there is something wrong with the way you `transform()` and `reverseTransform()`. A good way to debug would be to check your [ViewModel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers) in the [NormModel](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers) and [ModelData](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers).

<kbd>4</kbd> Maybe you have a lifecycle callback

```
/** @PrePersist */
public function doStuffOnPrePersist()
{
    $this->name = 'changed from prePersist callback!';
}
```

Comment: Hi Patt thanks for the response!

I'm not using any event listeners or lifecycle callbacks. 


Before the bind, `$requestform = $this->get('request')->request->get('finance_gstbundle_documenttype');$requestform['name']` = 'cat'.
After bind, `$form->get('name')->getData()` = 'at'

Also, the codebase is excactly the same on dev / preprod boxes. Do you think it's possible that some server setting that's overriding the application could cause the discrepancy?

Comment: Ok no worries, it was worth a shot :)